# Add the name of a cell to the name of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm quite new to conditional formatting in excel. What I need is to make the name of a cell appear in the cell next to it after the name inside that cell: For example I have this:

[image]

I just need the NAME1 "Saraburi" appear after the NAME_2 "Chalermphrakiet" to give "Chalermphrakiet Saraburi".

I've tried the left formula but it is leading me nowhere. I've looked around the website and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",A2)
```

where the middle `" "` gives you a space between the items.